# How to backup from .mdf database that I created

Tags: c#

I created a `.mdf` database file with Visual Studio 2008. I can retrieve and insert data into database but when I want to backup I receive an error.

My code:

```
string con = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|C:\test\Data|\DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

connect = new SqlConnection(con);
connect.Open();

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"backup database [" + System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\Data\\DB.mdf] to disk ='"+str+"' with init,stats=10",connect);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connect.Close();

MessageBox.Show("The support of the database was successfully performed", "Back", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

The error is:

> *error : invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.*

Comment: +1`For providing a enough information on your first post! Welcome!

Answer (score 1):

This is for SQL Server 2012 and .NET 4.0.1 only.

If you have those, you should be able to use AttachDbFilename.

Anyway, if you have an .MDF for embedded database and the instance is not running, you can just copy .MDF and .LDF to back up.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your connection string is incorrect.

Try this one:

```
string con = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\test\Data\DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
```

For more options, have a look at: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005

Comment: Exactly - **either** it's a full, complete path (as you have shown), **or then** it uses the `|DataDirectory|` "macro" - something like: `@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";` - but one cannot mix the two

Answer (score 0):

just use your connection string as

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["<your connection string name from your app.config file>"].ConnectionString);
```

i tried it and it worked for me.