# Backup database from the database attached with program in c# by programming

Tags: mysql, database

When the connection string is like

`Data Source=IMMENSE-01\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dipar;Integrated Security=True`

I can use this query to backup database

`backup database dipar to disk ='F:\DBBackup\dipar.bak' with init,stats=10`

But when I keep the database along with the program to make a executable file, the connection string is like

`Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\dipar.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True`

and the query to take backup `backup database dipar to disk ='F:\DBBackup\dipar.bak' with init,stats=10` Says database not found.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, my first answer was incorrect.

> If you're using the AttachDbFileName= approach in your connection
>   string, you cannot use BACKUP DATABASE since that database file is not
>   really attached to the SQL Server Express instance. That's one of the
>   many drawbacks and shortcomings of that approach –  marc_s

From: [How to create database backup, when DB not stored in Microsoft SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746664/how-to-create-database-backup-when-db-not-stored-in-microsoft-sql-server)